# Measure on the set of orbits of a flow via the von Neumann crossed products?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, topological-groups, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose we're given an action (possibly: ergodic) of a group G (possibly: uncountable) on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ (possibly: a standard probability space).

**Question/reference request:** is there a natural/standard way of using the von Neumann crossed product $L^{\infty} X \rtimes G$ to introduce a measure on the orbit space $X/G$ (or some representation thereof)?

**Thoughts:** the pushforward measure doesn't seem all that natural (e.g. the quotient Borel structure isn't always generated by the quotient topology, and for ergodic flows we get that each set of orbits is null or conull). I was wondering if there's some known alternative measure.

Comment: One “representation” of X/G is the action groupoid X//G of G on X.  The Haar measure on G and the given measure on X combine together to produce a measure on X//G (in the sense of groupoids).  If the action of G on X is free, then X//G is equivalent to X/G.  If the action is nonfree, then arguably X//G is a better quotient than X/G.

Comment: @DmitriP. Thank you! Do you know any good standard references on this?

Comment: In the smooth case: Weinstein, The volume of a differentiable stack.  The measurable case is analogous.

Comment: @DmitriP. great, thanks! Do you know if the groupoid approach in any obvious way related to the vN crossed product construction I mentioned?

Comment: @DmitriP. And a very naïve question re: the obtained groupoid measure on X//G. Is there a meaningful way to compare that measure with the pushforward measure on X/G? Or are they altogether different beasts?

Comment: The von Neumann cross product is the groupoid convolution von Neumann algebra of the measurable groupoid X//G.

Comment: Assume the Haar measure is normalized so that its total volume is 1.  If the action of G on X is free, then the measures on X//G and X/G are identified with each other, as observed by Weinstein in the smooth case, since the map X//G→X/G is a Morita equivalence of groupoids.  In the general case, the measure on X/G might be a pushforward of the measure on X/G, but they will no longer correspond to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149784/discussion-between-stepan-plyushkin-and-dmitri-p).

Comment: @DmitriP. Thanks again! I was prompted by the website to move the discussion to chat. Hope that's fine with you. :)

Comment: “Does Weinstein's construction simplify considerably if the manifold is, say, just $R^{2n}$ and we've got a smooth (possibly: non-free) uncountable group of Lebesgue measure preserving transformations?”: As far as I know, having R^{2n} as a space does not result in significant simplifications.

Comment: “I've been chasing definitions and it seems to me that a differentiable stack can be viewed as a collections of equivariant maps from a G-bundle to X. In case when G acts freely, any equivariant map is injective, and the image of any such map is just a member of X/G. Does that sound correct to you?”: Yes, this is one out of many ways to describe the homotopy quotient X//G: a U-point of X//G is a principal G-bundle P→U together with a G-equivariant map P→X.

Comment: “In the general non-free case, once we have a Weinstein measure on X//G, will it somehow induce a measure on X/G?”: Yes, see Definition 3.3 and the paragraph after it in Weinstein's paper.

Comment: “I presume, then, that in the free case, once we get a Weinstein measure on X//G, we can recover a measure on X/G by setting, for $A \subset X/G$, $\mu(A)$ to be just the Weinstein measure on the set of morphisms whose images give us the set $A$, whenever the Weinstein measure is defined. Were you saying that such measure will coincide with the pushforward measure on $X/G$?”: The pushforward measure on X/G is identified at the beginning of Section 5 in Weinstein's paper.  If the action is free, the displayed formula on page 365 seems to answer your question in the affirmative.

Comment: @DmitriP. Thank you so much! Incredibly helpful stuff. 

Quick follow-up questions (hopefully, the last ones!): 

1) If we have a relatively open compact subset of $X/G$, $U$, such that the intersection of $U$ with the part of $X/G$ over which $G$ is regular is empty, then Weinstein measure of $U$ will turn out to be zero. And this, in itself, does not imply that the pushforward measure of $U$ (with respect to $\pi: X \rightarrow X/G$) has to be zero as well. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: 2) Do you think that, in general, we should expect there to be some such sets U (i.e. relatively open compact that do not intersect any part of $X/G$ where $G$ is regular)?

Comment: And finally: 3) Re: relative compactness and openness (Definition 3.3). This cannot be with respect to the standard quotient topology on $X/G$. Is it with respect to a topology that $X/G$ inherits from the Grothendieck topology on $X//G$? And if so, is it easy to see what that topology on $X/G$ looks like (at least in simple cases, e.g. when $G$ is the group of translations on $\mathbb{R}^n$)? Thanks!